# Android: While opening pdf "this file could not be accessed". c#

Tags: c#, android, pdf, android-intent, xamarin

I have an app that builds a listView of all the PDFs in a specified folder already located on the Android machine. The file path and name are stored in an array called `files[]` and I can grab a full path with `files[e.Position]`.

Here is my C# code

```
public void documentListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {       
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(files[e.Position]);


            Android.Net.Uri pdfPath = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(files[e.Position]);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            intent.SetDataAndType(pdfPath, "application/pdf");
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

           StartActivity(intent);
}
```

I have also added this to my manifest:

```
    <uses-persmission android:name="android.permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-persmission android:name="android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Every time I click the button it starts to open adobe (which is great) and then it says `This file could not be accessed`.

However, I can open the file directly by going to the folder. Any Ideas?

P.S. I have checked what files[e.Position] resolves to and it is correct  `/mnt/sdcard/PLA/testpdt.pdf`.

Comment: Can you check if Adobe will open that file outside of your app?  Is that file inside of your app's private storage?  I've had similar issues that occurred because the file's permissions were set such that only my application could open it.  Another solution would be to try copying the file into the device's public external storage and trying to use that path or using a ContentProvider.